# What is a working WebSockets implementation for ASP.NET WebApi with OWIN? (Can't be SignalR.)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, websocket

SignalR isn't an option because we need to support raw WebSocket connections which are only supported in SignalR Core.

This leaves precious few options that I'm aware of for WebSockets in ASP.NET. Right now, I'm using System.Net.WebSockets, but this is a very low-level library and without significant extra work it only supports half-duplex communication.

Other options such as [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp) and [SuperWebSocket](https://superwebsocket.codeplex.com/) have full-duplex but don't play nice with ASP.NET or OWIN.

Are there no other options? I'd rather not hand roll a WebSockets class.

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.WebSockets.AspNetWebSocket might be what you're looking for. [This page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/618032/Using-WebSocket-in-NET-Part) contains an example for MVC but is equally applicable for Web API.